# Biggest and smallest number without using conditional operator in python

Tags: python, logic

I wanted help in an exercise I need to find the smallest / largest number between a , b , c in python without using conditional operator

**Prohibited**
The input contains a single line with three integers a, b and c separated by a space in
white.

Exit
Your program should produce the largest value of a, b, and c. There must be no blanks and/or
empty lines in the output produced.

Example

input (a line)

```
1 2 3
```

Exit

```
3
```

Comment: What you've tried?  Can use `max` and `min` for the assignment?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the `input` numbers is interactively from the user.  You could try to use `max` and `min` to get the largest and smallest number, and avoid using `conditional` operator.   Let me know if there is any question.

```
lst = input('type in three numbers: (sep. by spaces)').split()  # type in 11 22 3

print(lst)   # ['11', '22', '3']  for example, 

print(f' largest number: {max((lst), key=int)} ')  # 22
```

Comment: perfectly what i expected